# How to create a function that will only accept types that can be converted toJson with spray-json

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I have a function that will take a parameter of some type, convert that parameter toJson and then return it. The issue here is that my function can't call .toJson on the parameter because it's not aware of it.

Example:

```
def convertToJson[A](toConvert: A): JsValue = 
  toConvert.toJson
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm wondering how could I make something similar to this work? How could I generalize this function to work with all my serializable case classes? There isn't some unifying type that I could add that would allow this function to accept all serializable case class.

If more information is needed or a better explanation is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `toJson` method is provided by the implicit extension `PimpedAny`, which you have to import:

```
import spray.json._

def convertToJson // ...
```

Then, spray-json uses the `spray.json.JsonWriter[A]` typeclass to determine, what can be serialized. You have to provide evidence, that your `A` can be viewed as a `JsonWriter[A]`. There are two ways to do that:

```
def convertToJson[A: JsonWriter](toConvert: A): JsValue = 
  toConvert.toJson
```

and

```
def convertToJson[A](toConvert: A)(implicit writer: JsonWriter[A]): JsValue = 
  toConvert.toJson
```

With the former being syntactic sugar for the latter.

**Update**:

You can also skip the `toJson` extension and use `JsonWriter` directly:

```
def convertToJson[A](toConvert: A)(implicit writer: JsonWriter[A]): JsValue = 
  writer.write(toConvert)
```

which would be exactly, what `toJson` is doing.